# strategy / payoff matrix

Tags: diagrams, matrices

I am trying to create a strategy matrix in LaTeX such as 
[image]

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. I would like there to be two values in each cell, aligned as in this diagram.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution using tabular (a tikz solution follows).

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
&&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Payoff Matrix}\\
&&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Firm B}\\
&&Low Price&High Price\\
\cline{3-4}
\raisebox{-0.25cm}{\rotatebox{90}{A}}&\multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{Low Price}&
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}}{\hfill $10$\newline $10$\hfill}&
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{\hfill $5$\newline $25$\hfill}\\
\cline{3-4}
\raisebox{-0.25cm}{\rotatebox{90}{Firm}}&\multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{Low Price}&
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}}{\hfill $5$\newline $25$\hfill}&
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{\hfill $20$\newline $20$\hfill}\\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
```

Here is the result

[image]

Here is a tikz solution: (note: I fixed an alignment problem in the code, but I did not update the picture)

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[matrix of math nodes,every odd row/.style={align=right},every even row/.style={align=left},every node/.style={text width=1.5cm},row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm] (m) {
10&5\\
10&25\\
5&20\\
25&20\\
};
\draw (m.north east) rectangle (m.south west);
\draw (m.north) -- (m.south);
\draw (m.east) -- (m.west);

\coordinate (a) at ($(m.north west)!0.25!(m.north east)$);
\coordinate (b) at ($(m.north west)!0.75!(m.north east)$);
\node[above=5pt of a,anchor=base] {Low Price};
\node[above=5pt of b,anchor=base] {High Price};

\coordinate (c) at ($(m.north west)!0.25!(m.south west)$);
\coordinate (d) at ($(m.north west)!0.75!(m.south west)$);
\node[left=2pt of c,text width=1cm]  {Low Price};
\node[left=2pt of d,text width=1cm]  {High Price};

\node[above=18pt of m.north] (firm b) {Firm B};
\node[left=1.6cm of m.west,rotate=90,align=center,anchor=center] {Firm A};

\node[above=5pt of firm b]  {Payoff Matrix};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]